# Login with AWS cognito using Node JS

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am using Angular2 as front-end and Node JS as backend. I have to use AWS cognito for login process.

Here I have used commands for create user, First time Authenticate, Password Challenge and Login process.

I have done these steps using CLI. Can any one suggest me how can I do this in Node JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to install `npm` modules as follows:

```
npm install aws-sdk --save
npm install amazon-cognito-identity-js-node --save
npm install node-cmd --save
```

Now, after installation of these modules, you need to use them in your file by using

```
var AWS          = require('aws-sdk');
var cmd          = require('node-cmd');
var CognitoSDK   = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js-node');
```

Now you can use the commands as follows:
For example for create user:

```
 cmd.get('aws cognito-idp admin-create-user --user-pool-id <user pool id> --username <username> --user-attributes Name=email,Value=<emailid@domain.com>  Name=phone_number,Value=<9876543210> Name=email_verified,Value=True Name=phone_number_verified,Value=True --temporary-password <password> --desired-delivery-mediums "EMAIL" "SMS"');
```

The above is same command which is used in CLI to create user. You can use other commands also like above.

Thank you!

Comment: if we are using node-cmd then why are we using other modules (aws-sdk and amazon-cognito-identity-js-node)?

Comment: AWS is used for configuration like  AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
        region: region
    });

Comment: Actually these have some dependency on each others so better you should keep them

Answer (score 4):

You can refer the below sample project from AWSLABS 
[cognito-sample-nodejs](https://github.com/awslabs/cognito-sample-nodejs)

You can also use the [amazon-cognito-identity-js-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js-node) for better development.

You can use something like below in node

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var CognitoSDK = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js-node');

AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails = CognitoSDK.AuthenticationDetails;
AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool = CognitoSDK.CognitoUserPool;
AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser = CognitoSDK.CognitoUser;
```

Comment: I have used the amazon-cognito-identity-js-node module and got the IdToken. that is good but Using CLI I was getting  "ChallengeName": "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED" in JSON response but not by using this module. Can you please let me know how can I get this. Because I have to user either user is using temp password or has he updated the password?